# How do I split DNS routing between a domain and subdomain to 2 different locations?

Tags: domain-name-system

I have a domain registered with namecheap: `ezsaltdelivers.com`. I set the custom DNS to route to my Bluehost VPS using `ns1.bluehost.com` and `ns2.bluehost.com`. This all works fine. Website up and running, DNS routing.

But then I realized I need to make a change. I need `ezsaltdelivers.com` to route to a Wix website (instead of the Bluehost nameservers), and I need my new subdomain (`app.ezsaltdelivers.com`) to route to the Bluehost nameservers. Suddenly I'm out of my depth.

I created the subdomain `app.ezsaltdelivers.com` on my Bluehost VPS account - seemed to work, though propagation isn't done yet.

There is a Namecheap doc titled [How do I link my domain to my Wix account](https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/1247/2208/how-do-i-link-my-domain-to-my-wix-account/), but that doesn't seem to address the scenario of splitting DNS pointers between primary domain and subdomain.

There is also a Namecheap doc titled [How to Create a Subdomain for my Domain](https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/9776/2237/how-to-create-a-subdomain-for-my-domain/), but I'm a bit confused which option I should choose for my scenario.

There is another post here on ServerFault that is similar to my question (titled [DNS setup for a domain and its subdomain to point to different hosts](https://serverfault.com/questions/344411/dns-setup-for-a-domain-and-its-subdomain-to-point-to-different-hosts)), but the hosts and registrars are different and I'm not sure if it's quite my same scenario.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: If you change the nameservers for your root domain to Wix, so they control the DNS records for the domain, then any delegation for your subdomain would need to be configured there via Wix, not via Namecheap since they no longer have control over that side of things.